# Fetch the top nine rows and then get a tenth row with the total of everything else

Tags: sql

I want to fetch nine rows of the count of experts in the country and the name of the country ordered in descending order by count of experts. For the tenth row I want to add a row that shows the total number of experts from all other countries.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT count(expert_id) as total_expert, cc.country_name
 FROM expertsdb.ci_experts_master cem
 INNER JOIN ci_city cct ON cct.city_id = cem.city_
 INNER JOIN ci_country cc ON cc.country_id = cct.country_id
 WHERE cem.city_ IS NOT NULL 
 order by total_expert 
 limit 9 desc
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help, as would a database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an "other" category after the first 9.  You can use window functions:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN seqnum <= 9 THEN country_name ELSE 'rest' END) as country_name,
       SUM(total_expert)
FROM (SELECT cc.country_name, count(*) as total_expert,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM expertsdb.ci_experts_master cem JOIN
           ci_city cct
           ON cct.city_id = cem.city_ JOIN
           ci_country cc
           ON cc.country_id = cct.country_id
      WHERE cem.city_ IS NOT NULL 
     ) c
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN seqnum <= 9 THEN country_name ELSE 'rest' END)
ORDER BY seqnum ;
```

Comment: hi this first 9 is based on the count of experts grouped country wise and not sequence number it is rank wise

Comment: If i run my code. the output is 
14 Germany
3 United States
1 New Zealand
1 Bosnia and Herzegovina
1United Arab Emirates
1Belgium

Comment: @SumiPrasad . . . That is what this answer does.